# Inserir quantidade X de caracteres em campo SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Olá, tenho dois bancos BDMCOM1 e BDMCOM1_V3_ALEA, sendo que as duas tem uma tabela chamada SaldoDeProdutos e o campo chamado CodigodoProduto, na tabela do banco BDMCOM1, o CodigoDoProduto tem 5 dígitos, na tabela do outro banco o codigoDoProduto tem 8 dígitos...

Gostaria de selecionar todos os dados da tabela `SaldoDeProdutos`, que possui uma coluna `CodigoDoProduto` cujo formato do campo é algo como 00001, e inserir na outra tabela do banco `BDMCOM1_V3_ALEA` já incluindo 3 zeros à esquerda para completar os 8 dígitos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer inserir os zeros na seleção, pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT A.*, REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(B.CODIGO)) + B.CODIGO
FROM TABELA_A A
INNER JOIN TABELA_B B ON (...)
```

A ideia é que não importa se faltam 3 ou menos zeros. `REPLICATE` desta forma conta os zeros que faltam e os coloca pra você.

[Veja mais sobre a função `REPLICATE` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174383.aspx).

A inserção seria algo assim:

```
INSERT TABELA_B (/* Campos aqui */)
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(A.CODIGO)) + A.CODIGO as CODIGO, -- Mais campos aqui
FROM TABELA_A
WHERE -- Alguma condição aqui.
```

Estou supondo que o tipo da coluna `CODIGO` suporta zeros à esquerda, como `varchar` ou `nvarchar`.

---

**EDIT**

Formatando a resposta para o restante das informações, fica assim:

```
INSERT BDMCOM1_V3_ALEA (CODIGODOPRODUTO, /* Demais campos aqui */)
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(A.CODIGODOPRODUTO)) + A.CODIGODOPRODUTO as CODIGODOPRODUTO, -- Mais campos aqui
FROM SaldoDeProdutos
WHERE -- Alguma condição aqui, não é obrigatório este where.
```

Comment: Cigano, nao deu certo aqui, deixa eu detalhar mais... Um banco eh BDMCOM1 e tem a tabela SaldoDeProdutos e um campo chamado CodigoDoProduto com varchar 5, o outro banco é o BDMCOM1_V3_ALEA e tem a tabela SaldoDeProduto e o campo CodigoDoProduto com varchar 8.

Quero pegar por exemplo o 00001 do BDMCOM1 e botar no BDMCOM1_V3_ALEA assim: 00000001.

Tem como editar a resposta nesse padrão?

Comment: Pode por favor editar sua pergunta com estes detalhes?

Comment: Ok, já Editado.

Comment: @JadsonMedeiros Veja se agora ficou mais claro.

Comment: Se não tive acende a luz.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Sim, mas você colocou o resto das colunas ou só copiou e colou o que eu coloquei?

Comment: Colei o codigo e substituí umas coisinhas, entao o erro deu só no FROM, no caso inserir mais colunas é opcional e nao ocorreria erro caso tenha apenas uma, nao?

Comment: A quantidade de colunas do `INSERT` precisa ser igual à quantidade de colunas de `SELECT`. Não pode ter vírgula entre a última coluna e `FROM`.

Comment: Blz, mas tarde vejo isso aqui, obg.

Comment: Cigano, deu certo, obg, era apenas a virgula mesmo, porem agora me deparei com um campo com quantidade 1,00 e outro campo 1,000, no caso tentei adaptar esse trecho: REPLICATE('0', 4 - LEN, e nao rolou, neste caso é pegar o 1,000 e mandar pro outro banco como 1,00.

Comment: Acho que vale a pena fazer outra pergunta, não?